What is the meaning of the pipe symbol in XPath?
<xsl:for-each select="$vTerm/termVocabulary | $vDefaults/termCat[not($vTerm/termVocabulary)]">
I initially thought it was an "or" but I don't think that is correct.
I can't find anything on the internet about using the pipe symbol in that fashion.

Known in XPath as union operator

As @LMC says, it's a set union operator. But it can look like "or" because it is often used equivalently. It's common in XSLT to see XPath expressions like A[B | C] which selects A elements which have either B children or C children. This could be written equivalently as A[B or C]. In both cases, nodesets are being converted to boolean values implicitly: i.e. A[boolean(B | C)] and A[boolean(B) or boolean(C)]. A nodeset is "true" when non-empty. Obviously, if and only if either of the nodesets B or C is non-empty, then the union B | C is non-empty.
